# How to get columns of middle table in Many-to-many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to get quantity from receipt instance ?

I have 3 table: receipts, receipt_foods, foods
I want to get columns of receipt_foods, such as quantity, from receipt instance.

```
class Receipt
  # columns: id, place
  has_many :receipt_foods
  has_many :foods, through: :receipt_food
end

class ReceiptFood
  # columns: id, quantity, receipt_id, food_id
  belongs_to :receipt
  belongs_to :food
end

class Food
  # columns: id, name
  has_many :receipt_foods
  has_many :receipts, through: :receipt_food
end
```

I want to respond json like that:

```
{ "receipts": [
  "receipt": {
     "id": 1,
     "place": "supermarket",
     "foods": [ {
        "food": {
           "id": 1,
           "quantity": 12, // how to echo this ?
           "name": "apple" } 
....
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get quantity like following

```
receipt_foods = @receipt.receipt_foods 
receipt_foods.each do |receipt_food|
  puts receipt_food.quantity 
end
```